# I cant find IC from code printed in ic

Tags: identification

I have a small SOT-26 (6 pins) device that is used in a MOSFET-based SMPS. It may be a PWM controller to switch the MOSFET. I need to identify it, but I can't find the component code anywhere at all. The code is 30653. Like in this image

[image: Component]

Answer (score 5):

It does look like a SiFirst SF1530.  [image]

http://www.chinesechip.com/chipFile/2015-07/SF1530-6119-0.pdf

update, some similar parts from other manufacturers:
***On-bright*** ob2263, ***Winsemi*** WS2283, ***TI*** ucc28700-q1, ***MAxim*** MAX5021-MAX5022

Comment: we also want to know cross reference of SF1530 in Branded company like st,ti,ON semi,Fairchild etc.

Comment: Sir can we replace OB2263 directly in SMPS board or some peripheral component is also required to change.

Comment: @PradipBharambe, if you look at both IC's characteristics, you can see they are almost clones. Some differences, ex. 50ns on T_blanking, UVLO , but pin to pin compatible; I would install a OB2263 with same components, but do check if anything is damaged before

Comment: @PradipBharambe compare the datasheets : https://www.cnledw.com/inter/upload/2011082311525256277.pdf and http://file.yizimg.com/332467/2010080308450435.pdf

Comment: @PradipBharambe if older comps failed and destroyed the older ic, it will destroy the new, should check before.

Comment: OB2263 is not available ,OB2269 is easily available we want to drive MOSFET by OB2269 how do i replace this ,is other peripheral need to change.I will change pcb footprint ,that is not a problem for me.pls suggest